# SQL where LIKE and json_encode

Tags: php, sql, database, json, sql-like

I have one big problem.

My databases column look like this:

```
{"79":"novej nazev ","53":"","54":"0","55":"0","56":"\u0159\u0159\u0159\u0159\u0159","57":"","58":"","59":"","60":"","61":"","62":"","63":"","64":"","65":"","66":"","67":"","68":["",""],"69":"0","70":["",""],"71":["",""],"72":["",""]}
```

There is array and json_encode(array)

So now I would like search in database some word with diacritics but json_encode convert diacritics to (\u0159\u0159\u0159\u0159\u0159)

Ok no problem so I was convert searchs word by `$search_word=json_endoce(SEARCH WORD);`.

Now I will seach by script:
`data LIKE '%$search_word%'`  but nothing so will not get forim database

So where i have been doing wrong?

Comment: Check the default encoding your database uses, you might need to set it to utf-8.

Comment: My database is utf-8..
I was try search only "\u0159" and it is do, but when i was search "\u0159\u0159\u0159\u0159\u0159" so not working why?

Comment: could you provide the whole query?

Comment: I used NetteFramework (www.nette.org) but query is

$ot=json_encode($hodnoty['slovo']);
$zakazky=$this->database->table('others')->where(data LIKE ?','%'.$ot.'%')

Comment: Did you escaped the backslashes? Try `\\u0159\\u0159\\u0159\\u0159\\u0159` Because `SELECT '\u0159\u0159\u0159\u0159\u0159'` becomes `u0159u0159u0159u0159u0159`

Comment: I suspect `json_encode` adds surrounding `{}` and quoting, and is not suitable for encoding a single string for searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to not escape unicode characters with json_encode :

```
json_encode($value, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Unicode is well supported in MySQL. You don't need to escape those characters.